# How to select first not null value from a single column in a table.?

Tags: sql

Below is the situation:

Table : Claims

Data:

```
Claim id     ex-code     SEQ_no

A1                         1
A1            dvv          2
A1            abc          3
A2            xyz          1
A2                         2
```

I want to pull claim id and ex-code.. Only first not null value of ex-code should be used.. Is there any function for this or should we use sub-query..?

Comment: Which Database you have used... eg. MSSQL, MySQL...

Answer (score 2):

For MSSQL, Try this :

```
SELECT TOP 1 ClaimId, ExCode,SEQNo FROM Claim WHERE ExCode IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
  FROM claims
  WHERE ex-code IS NOT NULL;
```

[I think it might be helpful for you](http://www.razorsql.com/articles/ms_sql_server_limit_query.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM [Claims] WHERE ex-code <> null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT claim_id, ex_code, seq_no
FROM Claims
WHERE ex_code NOT NULL
GROUP BY claim_id
ORDER BY claim_id
```

As far as I know, `GROUP BY` returns the first value (unless `GROUP_CONCAT` is used). So this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
This query return Claim ID wise First records which is not null...

```
WITH getFirstNonNull AS (
SELECT Claimid,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Claimid ORDER BY SEQ_no) AS RowNum , ex-code FROM Claims
WHERE ex-code IS NOT NULL 
) SELECT * FROM getFirstNonNull WHERE RowNum = 1
```